# Can the "viewed number" on a question have better formatting?

Tags: feature-request, views, information-display, numbers

A few times now I have glanced at the "viewed" field for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery?rq=1) and had to count digits to figure out if it has been viewed 4 million times or 400 000 times.

Adding a thousand separator would go a long way in making that number easier to read.  I would also accept "viewed 400k" since I understand that it is an approximate number anyway.

Changing my browser locale doesn't seem to change the look of that number, so I guess it doesn't use local aware formatting.

Comment: [Related on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251510/should-the-views-count-in-the-sidebar-be-formatted) (also it is bugging me much, so [I have a dupe](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255722/put-delimiter-in-views-count) :)

Comment: I know the other question has a different approach, but the general issue is the same "make view count numbers better". Add your idea from your question here as an answer to the proposed dupe :)